# Need advice for testing in php

Tags: php, testing

I'm very new to tests. I have a webapp that stores books and informations about books.

If i call my route `/store/` it trigger my `store` methods and creating a new book into my database. This are the simplified methods:

`Book.php` class file:

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->bookService = new BookService();
}

public function store() {
    $input = /* get post input values */
    $this->createDatabaseEntry($input);
}

private function createDatabaseEntry($input) {
    // Creating database entry
    $book = /* bla bla */

    $languages = $this->bookService->fetchLanguages($book->goodreads_id);
    // And here i loop over the $languages and store them all in a extra table.
}
```

And here i have an other Service class `BookService.php`:

```
public function fetchLanguages($goodreads_id) {
    // Here i make an guzzle http call to a other service from goodreads.com
}
```

How do i test this without making a http request to goodreads? I need to verify the languages are in the database. I can work with fixtures for `fetchLanguages()`. But how can i stub/mock (i don't know the correct term) this function?

I using Laravel and PHPUnit.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is exactly this - stubbing the BookService class. Since you instantiate it directly however, it won't be so easy to stub it. You should inject it to your Book class, so you can inject a stub in the tests (either via a constructor injection or by providing a setter to overwrite $this->bookService).

A typical setup looks like this:

```
$serviceMock = $this->getMock('BookService');
$serviceMock->method('fetchLanguages')->willReturn(<some hard-coded-result-here>);
$book = new Book($serviceMock);
```